# Copy file to another directory based on a part of the filename

Tags: ruby

I have a directory with many files, which are named based on a given pattern, for instance: `User_TR1_ES-ES.csv`, `User_TR1_FR-FR.csv` `User_TR2_DE-DE.csv`. The destination directory contains subfolders like these: `folder_TR1`, `folder_TR2`. I need to copy each files that contain `TR1` in the basename within directory `folder_TR1`, and successively with the rest of the files. My code so far:

```
#I made an array with the list of files in original folder
file_list = Dir.children(output)

#I captured the parts of the file name that I'm interested in two variables
file_list.each do |file|
    user_chars = file[5] + file[6] + file[7]
    lang_chars = file[9] + file[10] + "-" + file[12] + file[13]
end

#Now I create a new path, in order to make the copy
original_path = File.join(output, "User_#{user_chars}_#{lang_chars}.csv")
new_path = #where I'm having issues

#in order to make the copy, I'd make the following
FileUtils.cp(original_path, new_path)
```

I just can't proceed on copying from one place to the desired folder, by following their filenames. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So taking a path like this:

```
path = "/path/to/User_TR1_ES-ES.csv"
```

You want to extract `TR1` from it, you can use

```
id = File.basename(path).split("_")[1]
```

Now `id` will equal "TR1". From here you want to copy it, so you can just supply the destination folder:

```
target_dir = "/path/to/folder_#{id}"
FileUtils.copy path, target_dir
```

Comment: This was perfect! Just to understand: the `split("_")` separates the string whenever if finds a `_`, right? Result is an array of three elements, with `[1]` grabbing the `TR1` I wanted. Is all this correct?

Comment: @Topa_14 exactly. You can also do this kind of thing with Regex, which is much more powerful, but also more difficult